Cast STRING as FLOAT in Databricks
I m trying to cast an amount which is stored as STRING into a FLOAT using CAST function and string such as "4166.691" get type casted into 4166.69091796875
select cast('184435.290' as float) gives 184435.296875
Why does this happen ? How can I correctly type cast this value ?
Edit:
select cast('184435.290' as double) seems to work ok
I am not sure why this is so ?

When casting a string to a float in Spark, it may result in a loss of precision due to the internal representation of floating-point numbers.
This issue is not specific to Spark but is a characteristic of floating-point number storage in computers.
I have tried the below:
df_casted = df.withColumn("amount_casted", col("amount").cast("double"))

df_casted.show()

Results:
+----------+-------------+
|    amount|amount_casted|
+----------+-------------+
|  4166.691|     4166.691|
|184435.290|    184435.29|
+----------+-------------+

To correctly type cast the value without any loss of precision, you can use the double data type instead of float.
The double data type provides more precision than float and can represent decimal numbers with greater accuracy.
